# Pandas make columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a pandas dataframe which looks like the following picture:

[image]

Every year is a new column, but i want them in one column called year.

It should look similar like this dataframe:

[image]

Anybody got an idea, how i can achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use the melt method,  something like this

```
df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['country','continent'], var_name="year", value_vars=[str(x) for x in range(1850,2011)])
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach.
For this to work you need to have all "name" columns as index.

Here is a sample if you only have Country and values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Country": ["China", "Lithuania"],
    "2000": [2,10],
    "2022": [10,44],
})

df.set_index("Country").stack()
```

Results in

```
Country
China      2000     2
           2022    10
Lithuania  2000    10
           2022    44
dtype: int64
```